# Rails 3: Finding all categories that have parent_categories with parent_categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a complex `Category` model that has parent_categories (which are categories themselves). I want to create a scope to find all 3rd level categories (categories with parents that have parents).

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :parent_id, :category_image_attributes

  has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

How would I accomplish this in ActiveRecord?

== UPDATE ==

So I eventually figured it out myself, but I'm going to leave this question up to see if there are any more efficient ways to solve it:

```
def self.all_third_level_categories
  all_ids_of_categories_with_parents = Category.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL").map { |c| c.id }
  Category.find_all_by_parent_id(all_ids_of_categories_with_parents)
end
```

Comment: You should probably set the category level when a category is created/modified. Too much stress on the DB after that

Comment: Just looking at one line, try doing `Category.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL").ids` instead of `.map { |c| c.id }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @bcd 's comment, the implementation you provide needs n-1 queries to fetch the objects with depth n, which can get nasty very soon.

On the other hand a slight overhead on save where

```
def set_level
  self.level = parent_category.level + 1
end
```

can clear things up.

Comment: yeh I agree. I'm going to just redo it and add a level column and do something like Category.where("level = 2 AND parent_id = #{parent_category.id}"). I implemented a lot of it using the other way, but it is way too complex and does not feel efficient